# Irreducible subgroups of $\text{GL}(2,p)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory

I just wonder any sources that provides the list of all minimal irreducible subgroups of $\text{GL}(2,p)$. Here the term "minimal" means there is no proper subgroup that is irreducible. A list of maximal subgroups of $\text{PSL}(2,p)$ is available [here](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEcQFjAD&url=http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.100.7645&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=0VxBUfnXGo2mkgXY-YGQDA&usg=AFQjCNGDKcUhp920XTPSnnQD1ZSxW5p3jQ&bvm=bv.43287494,d.dGI.). For some case, it is easy to know the subgroup is reducible, but generally I am not sure how to dig information from here. I think it would be good if there is some reference which provides full list of all irreducible subgroups.

I think first we need to know all the maximal subgroups of $\text{GL}(2,q)$. Since $\text{GL}(2,q)'=\text{SL}(2,q)$, so a maximal subgroup $M$ of $\text{GL}(2,q)$ contains $Z$ or $\text{SL}(2,q)$. If $M>Z$, then we look at the subgroups of $\text{PGL}(2,q)$; if $M>\text{SL}(2,q)$, then we look at the subgroups of $\text{PSL}(2,q)$. Then the next thing is that if you know a group is irreducible, how do you analyse the irreducibility of its subgroups? Since sometimes it seems not clear to me that how the subgroup acts on the vectors space. And I am also not too sure how to find the critical subgroups, that is the minimal one. Do we have any trick for treating this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say an "irreducible subgroup"?

Comment: @Alexander, regarding $\text{GL}(2,p)$ acts on the $2$-dimensional vector space $\text{GF}(p)^2$. The subgroup that is irreducible if it doesn't fix any proper subspace.

Answer (score 5):

The subgroups of ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ for prime powers $q$ were classified by Dickson in 1901. You can find the lists and proofs in Huppert's German book "Endliche Gruppen I". Of course you need the subgroups of ${\rm PGL}(2,p)$, which is twice as big, and then you need to check their inverse images in ${\rm GL}(2,p)$ for irreducibility. So you have some work to do!

I will have a go at listing the minimal irreducible groups, but it is a little complicated, and I may not get it absolutely right.

1. For odd primes $r$ dividing $p+1$, the cyclic group of order $r$.
2. The cyclic group of order $2^r$, where $2^{r-1}$ is the highest power of 2 dividing $p-1$.
3. The dihedral group of order $2r$ for odd primes $r$ dividing $p-1$.

I believe that is all when $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. (That case is simpler, because all elements of order 4 act irreducibly.) It is more complicated when
$p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. In that case, you also get:

1. The dihedral group $D_8$.
2. The quaternion group $Q_8$.
3. For odd primes $r$ dividing $p-1$, a group of order $4r$ contained in ${\rm SL}(2,p)$.
4. This is the complicated one. After doing some computations with $p=17$, I think, for all powers $2^r$ dividing $p-1$ with $r \ge 3$, there is a nonabelian group of order $2^{r+1}$ intersecting the scalar subgroup with order $2^{r-1}$.

Here is a bit more information on methods used. The maximal subgroups of ${\rm GL}(2,p)$ (with $p$ prime) are the imprimitive groups of order  $2(p-1)^2$, the semilinear groups of order $2(p^2-1)$, groups whose intersection with ${\rm SL}(2,p)$ is a double cover of $A_4$, $S_4$ or $A_5$, and groups containing ${\rm SL}(2,p)$. Since ${\rm SL}(2,p)$ itself is never minimal irreducible, we can forget about that, and the ones involving $A_4$, $S_4$ or $A_5$ all have a normal irredcuible subgroup $Q_8$, which is itself imprimitive and/or semilinear, so we can effectively forget about those.

So we can restrict attention to imprimitive and semilinear subgroups. The maximal semilinears have a cyclic subgroup of order $q^2-1$ which acts irreducibly but not absolutely irreducibly, and it is not hard to see that their minimal irreducible subgroups are those in classes 1 and 2 above.

So it remains to find the minimal irreducible subgroups of the maximal imprimitive subgroups. These are all conjugate, and one of them, $H$ say, consists of the monomial matrices, so we can just look for subgroups of $H$. So the group $D$ of diagonal matrices has index 2 in $H$ and is reducible. So a minimal irreducible $K$ will have a subgroup of $D$ of index 2. If $|K \cap D|$ is odd, then get the groups in class 3 above. As I noted before, if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then elements of order 4 act irreducible, and any other such subgroup would have an element of order 4, so would not be minimal irreducible. But it is more complicated when $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: good effort! Before we proceed further, I just generally wonder what kind of technique you used? See my additional elaboration in the post. Thanks

Comment: I have added a bit more information on this, which I hope is helpful.

Comment: @DerekHolt The groups of order $p(p-1)^2$ are missing in the list of maximal subgroups of ${\rm GL}(2,p)$.

Comment: @PeterMueller Yes you are right! Of course the question is about irreducible subgroups, so I was careless about the subgroups that are reducible.

Answer (score 4):

A belated addition: representatives of conjugacy classes of irreducible subgroups of GL(2, GF(q)) for finite fields of characteristic p at least 5 are described explicitly in the following paper:

Dane Flannery and E.A. O'Brien: Linear groups of small degree over finite fields. Internat. J. Algebra Comput. 15, 467-502, 2005.

The pdf file is available at www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien
The list is also available in Magma via the command

> IrreducibleSubgroups (n, q)

The paper also lists representatives for soluble irreducible subgroups of GL(3, q); those for insoluble subgroups of degree 3 were recently added by Barry Hurley.

Eamonn O'Brien

Comment: Welcome to MSE. please take a look at this page : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference